# Counter not correct after "lost" transaction

Tags: counters

We have a transaction that was sent more than 12 hours ago.  First it sat in mempool, not it reports to be "lost" - https://tzkt.io/tz1hB5K5FMcPFVLLitZa5ZiNjJrM5RjZG1Sd/operations/

But when we check for the next counter to use we get back this result:
curl https://mainnet-tezos.giganode.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1hB5K5FMcPFVLLitZa5ZiNjJrM5RjZG1Sd
{"balance":"2614688","counter":"10734190"}

Which indicate we should be using 10734191 for our next transaction - but that fails saying the counter is already used.

Comment: I have looked at the transaction and the branch is now about 2200 block ago - so we should be able to re-use the counter now but we can't.

Comment: Seems to be resovled now - after a node upgrade

Answer (score 0):

We were running a v8.3-2 server, didn't upgrade, so perhaps the tx got stuck in our local mempool due to the fact we were not synchronizing anymore.

Resolved after upgrading and getting synchronized back to tip.